# Error: The specified module could not be found-module.js:597 return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));

Tags: x86, azure-functions, 64-bit, visual-studio-debugging

```
Debugger listening on [::]:5858
module.js:597
  return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
                ^

Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\ash\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\1.13.2\cli_x64\edge\x86\edge_nativeclr.node\
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ashleychen.REDMOND\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\1.13.2\cli_x64\edge\edge.js:54:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
```

I'm running service by using AzureFunctions, the ERROR showed that 'The specified module could not be found'. However, when I tried to follow the path, there is existing the file named edge_nativeclr.node. I don't understand why the system could not find it.

```
type here
```

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check the answer? If it works you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Installing the old Visual Studio 2013 C++ Redistributable Package fixed the issue. Here is the download center link: https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=40784.

Make sure to choose the x86 version, as shown in the screenshot below.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4FNe.png)